# Is it possible to create an object interface on TypeScript that allows a flexible number/type of keys?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax

On creating a theme for a React component I was wondering what the best way to define an object type would be. Basically I have a react component that takes in a style object to create a theme. Such as below:

```
const datePickerTheme = {
    palette: {
        primary: "#f5f5f5",
        secondary: "#2b4450",
        tertiary: "#871111"
    },
    spacing: ["0px", "4px", "8px", "16px", "32px", "64px"],
};
```

it would be passed in to a datepicker component like so:

```
<DatePicker theme={datePickerTheme}/>
```

On type script it has an interface like so:

```
interface ITheme {
  palette: {
    primary: string,
    secondary?: string,
    tertiary?: string,
  },
  spacing: [],
}
```

However, I would like keep the interface open for future theme customizations for other possibilities. Basically one should be able to pass a theme of any kind and however many keys needed. Is there a way to define the interface so that it is flexible and open for such cases without using type "theme:any".

Comment: It is already allowed out of the box, you can pass something wider than `ITheme` (e.g. `<DatePicker theme={extendedTheme}/>`) where `extendedTheme` can be for example `interface ExtendedTheme extends ITheme { foo: string }`

Comment: thank you I forgot about this option :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want? You can add any key in `palette` object.

```
interface ITheme {
  palette: {
    primary: string,
    secondary: string,
    tertiary: string,
    [key: string]: string
  },
  spacing: [],
}
```

Or you can restrict the value of key by provide a `type`.

```
type PaletteKey = 'third' | 'fourth';

interface ITheme {
  palette: {
    primary: string,
    secondary: string,
    tertiary: string,
    [key: PaletteKey]: string
  },
  spacing: [],
}
```

#### Edited

For future customizations base on the `ITheme`, you can extend the interface.

For example:

```
interface IPalette {
  primary: string;
  secondary: string;
  tertiary: string;
}

interface ITheme {
  palette: IPalette;
  spacing: [];
}

type Breakpoints = {
  xs: number;
  sm: number;
  md: number;
  lg: number;
  xl: number;
};

interface CustomTheme extends ITheme {
  palette: IPalette & {
    error: string;
    success: string;
  };
  breakpoints: Breakpoints;
}
```

Comment: I want to do something like this:
interface ITheme {
  palette: {
    primary: string,
    secondary: string,
    tertiary: string,
  },
  spacing: string[],
  [key: string]?: string,
}

but I get an error parsing error? Not sure whats wrong?

Comment: I have add an edited answer for you, you can reference it.